# USB Soundcard stops playing after some time

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, soundcard

I have some weird behaviour with my external USB soundcard. It is a Focusrite Scarlett 2i4. It is connected through a USB 3 port to my laptop, running 18.04 LTS.

I can

- connect
- play music

with it. Everything normal so far. **The problem is that is stops putting out sound after a random amount of time. I have to replug the device, then it starts playing again. After some time, it stops to playback sound again.** This is a loop and super annoying when your music stops playing in the middle of a song.

When the music stops playing, software seems to still be working (see screenshot). Sound is still playing back in Ubuntu sound panel and also in pulseaudio everything seems to be alright.

Do you have an idea how to fix this or where the bug comes from?[image: No sound is played back, but controls look alright.]

**Edit 1**
Output from `$ usb-devices`

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=03 Dev#= 21 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  2
P:  Vendor=1235 ProdID=8200 Rev=04.1b
S:  Manufacturer=Focusrite
S:  Product=Scarlett 2i4 USB
C:  #Ifs= 6 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=20 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=20 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 1 #EPs= 1 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=20 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=01(audio) Sub=03 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=10 Driver=(none)
```

Comment: Seems like a driver issue. What model is your sound card and what driver are you using? If you can't answer this, run `lsusb` and `usb-devices`. If the system complains about usb-devices not being installed, just follow the instructions displayed by the error message so run: `sudo apt install usbutils`. Post the output in your question (modify it). I tend to think the issue is with the driver and you may need to update it.

Comment: @marko usbutils is installed and up to date.

Comment: I know this behavior from an other, more propertary, OS. Here the USB Power Management is the cause.
Reading https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.16/driver-api/usb/power-management.html says, you could try ``echo "-1" >/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend`` to disable the USB suspend. If it works, there are some hints of how to disable it permanent.